# Need to move login as customer module hook on top prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am unable to move login as customer module on top in Prestashop anyone who can help me need to change position for this module

Answer (score 0):

You can display the default module anywhere you want using this code:

`{widget name='ps_customersignin'}`

Comment: Where to add this code?

Comment: In the file, template file, where you want to display the content if this module :)